# BadZipFile: File is not a zip by importing keras

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, keras, imdb

When I run this code, I got the following [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJbTE.png). I have tried different techniques to get rid of this problem but couldn't.

May I request to someone who can help me to solve this issue. There are some solutions to the same problem but I couldn't get theirs points to fix it.

```
import numpy

from keras.datasets import imdb
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = imdb.load_data()

X = numpy.concatenate((X_train, X_test), axis=0)

y = numpy.concatenate((y_train, y_test), axis=0)
```

**Using Theano backend.**

```
BadZipFile    
/home/maaz/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/zipfile.py in _RealGetContents(self)
   1165             raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
   1166         if not endrec:
-> 1167             raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
   1168         if self.debug > 1:
   1169             print(endrec)

BadZipFile: File is not a zip file                            Traceback (most recent call 

BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

Answer (score 12):

This could have happened when a previous download has stopped for some reason resulting in a bad zip file in keras cache.
Try cleaning the keras dataset cache:
rm ~/.keras/datasets/*

Comment: yeah, if old dataset is not complete, then we need remove the cache. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.  I was downloading half way and then I had to go to work, so i stopped the download.  after work, I rerun the program, and it gives me the same message.  I have a Mac OS how I do clean the case from the dataset?  thanks.

i figured it out.  I actually had to do rm -R .keras/datasets on bash.