# How to clear dataset cache in keras?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I downloaded dataset about handwritten 10 digit via mnist but it stuck (not finished) so, when I run code again this error occur `BadZipFile: File is not a zip file` I think the answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44077111/badzipfile-file-is-not-a-zip-by-importing-keras)  can help me but I don't know how to run this code rm "~/.keras/datasets/*". I got invalid syntax error when I run in spyder and in cmd.

Comment: Are you running windows or linux

Comment: Windows 7 64bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"rm" is a Linux or MacOS command. For Windows, use "del".

You will need to find where keras datasets is under Windows. "~" is for the home directory under Linux or MacOS, but Windows could use %USERPROFILE% instead. Also, Windows uses "\" instead of "/" as the path delimiter, so the correct command for Windows could be -

"del %USERPROFILE%\.keras\datasets\*"

Answer (score 0):

rm is a linux command. to remove directories and sub-directories. The cmd that will work for you on windows is

`del /S C:\Path\to\keras\datasets\*`